# Cannot access network drive even though set privileges are valid

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, windows-server-2012

I have a network drive that can be accessed from different accounts belonging to different groups.

I've picked one such account and added all groups it belongs to, to a different account that has no access

to the drive. I relogged in, even restarted but I still cannot find the mapped network drive in explorer,

on that account. Why? I'm using Win Server 2016.

Comment: What you see in Explorer (network environment) has nothing to do with what you have access to (o computer and share level). Additionally mapping does not happen automatically, you have to you the share URL and map it to a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wording of your question, it sounds like you need to [map the network drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20map%20a%20network%20drive&oq=how%20yo%20map&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.6508j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Simply having access - which requires both the proper file and share permissions - is not enough for the drive to be seen in File Explorer.